# sublime text terminal will finish code before its done

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext

So, I will run code in sublime text, in the terminal below, if there was an input, it will ask for it, but then no further code will run, it will say finished afterwards but that is it.

I triple check the code every time but nothing seems to be wrong with it and it runs just fine in online interpreters. Did i not configure it correctly? I can't really figure out whats wrong with it and I'm not finding anyone with a similar problem online so I'm very confused on this.